# Swift can only see one value from firebase (retrieving data)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: compiler picture]

I can only see  username on my app not the age but I can see both values in the compiler not sure what's the problem.

```
func fetchDataa(){
    // var ref: DatabaseReference!

    //  ref = Database.database().reference()
    guard  let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String , AnyObject> else {return}
        let uid = snapshot.key
        let user = User(uid:uid , dictionary: dictionary)

        print(Thread.current)
        print(Thread.main)

        self.userAgeLabel.text = user.userage
        self.user = user
               self.userAgeLabel.text = user.userage
               self.user = user

        print(snapshot.value)
        // Get user value
        //  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        print(dictionary)


        // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

// by the way this is how I stored information as dictionary 
  // user info stored

```
  let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let userData = ["userName": userName,
            "userAge ": userAge] as [String? : Any]


        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users/\(userID ?? "")").setValue(userData)

      // ref.child("users").setValue(values)

}
```

// user initializer class

class User {

```
var username:String!
var userage:String!
var uid:String!
```

init (uid:String,dictionary:Dictionary) {

```
self.uid = uid

if let username = dictionary [ "userName" ] as? String{

    self.username = username
}

if let userage = dictionary [ "userAge" ] as? String{
    self.userage = userage
}
}
}
}
```

Firebase structure:

[image: Here]

Comment: What you mean by seeing in the compiler?

Comment: Also, could you post the code for the initializer of User class? The one you use that received aid and dictionary as parameters.

Comment: I have a picture for ajeferson its a compiler I believe that's run in Xcode that tells you about error or value etc.

Comment: What's the outcome of the `print(dictionary)` call?

Comment: the outcome is what ever value is stored in firebase {
    "userAge " = 22;
    userName = stop;
})
["userAge ": 22, "userName": stop]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUid).observeEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
 if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Anyobject] {
 let userAgeDictionary = dictionary["age"] as? String
print(userAgeDictionary)
```

Does this print out the age?

Comment: I am already getting the value on my compiler I just don't get the value of my age  label

Answer (score 0):

You've somehow put extra `"` around the `userAge` property. So the key is `"userAge"` **including** the double-quotes.

To get that value from the dictionary:

```
if let userage = dictionary [ "\"userAge\"" ] as? String{
    self.userage = userage
}
```

But going forward you'll probably want to fix the problem in the actual data: when entering a key in the Firebase console, you don't need to enter quotes around it, since keys are always strings.

Comment: puffelen it still didn't gave me user age in my label I changed the dictionary from my user class to if let userage = dictionary [ "\"userAge\"" ] as? String{
    self.userage = userage
}

Comment: The extra quotes are definitely the cause of problems. But there may be more wrong with your code. For example, you're attaching a listener to `Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUid)`, but the JSON you showed has a structure `/users/$pushid/$uid`, so with an extra level of push IDs in there. Your code doesn't seem to handle that.

Comment: I don’t think so ,but thanks for trying I hope I get the right direction to solve this issue?

Comment: its working now one of my dictionaries key were not matching with my firebase values thanks